# How to show data in textbox as dropdown as well as autocomplete too in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have textbox with autocomplete, When i click on textbox **An API is call with two parameters Pubid and Date** so **when user type data is displayed as drop-down with autocomplete functionality**.

Now I am trying **When user click on textbox data comes with drop-down without user typing and after data came user can filter data with autocomplete**

component.html

```
        <div class="form-field col-lg-12">
        <label class="label" for="message">Headline</label>
        <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
            <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        </div>
        <input [(ngModel)]="articleTitleKeyUp" (ngModelChange)="keyUpArticle(articleTitleKeyUp)" name="article"
            class="input-text js-input" type="text" required autocomplete="off">


        <div class="search-result" *ngIf="articles" style="max-height: 100px;">
            <ul style="margin:0; padding:5px; max-height: 100px;">
                <li *ngFor="let article of articles">
                    <a (click)="onClickArticle(article)">{{article.Title}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**component.ts**

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
 

    /* API Call for publications when page load */

    this.article.postPublication(null).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.allPubs = data.result;
      console.log(this.publications);
    });
  }

  onFocusPublication() {
    console.log(this.selectedDate);
  }

  /* POST article with PUB id and Date */

  keyUpPublication(e) {
    let k = e as string;
    let kl = k.length;

    this.publications = this.allPubs.filter((p) => {
      // let title = p.Title.toLowerCase()
      // return title.substring(0, kl) == k.toLowerCase()

      let title = p.Title + ' -' + p.city;
      return title.toLowerCase().includes(k.toLowerCase());
    });
  }

  onClickPublication(pub: IPub) {
    this.pubTitleKeyUp = pub.Title + ' -' + pub.city;
    this.selectedPub = pub;
    this.publications = [];
  }

  /* POST article with PUB id and Date */

  keyUpArticle(e) {
    if (!this.selectedPub) {
      return alert('Please select a Date and publication first!');
    }

    let k = e as string;
    let kl = k.length;

    if (this.allArticles?.length) {
      return (this.articles = this.allArticles.filter((p) => {
        let title = p.Title.toLowerCase();
        return title.substring(0, kl) == k.toLowerCase();
      }));
    }
    
    this.isLoading = true;

    this.article
      .postArticlesData({
        pubid: this.selectedPub.PubId,
        pubdate: this.selectedDate,
      })
      .subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
          this.isLoading = false;
          this.allArticles = data.result || [];

          this.articles = this.allArticles.filter((p) => {
            let title = p.Title.toLowerCase();
            return title.substring(0, kl) == k.toLowerCase();
          });
        },
        (e) => {
          this.isLoading = false;
        }
      );
    
  }

  /* When article gets clicked */
  onClickArticle(article) {
    // console.log(article);
    this.articleTitleKeyUp = article.Title;
    this.selectedArticle = article;
    this.articles = [];
  }

  /* ON pub change */
  onPubChange() {
    console.log(this.selectedDate, this.selectedPub);
  }

  /* ON submit form */
  onSubmit() {
    if (this.selectedArticle && this.selectedDate && this.selectedPub) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl(
        'delete-article/' + this.selectedArticle.ArticleID
      );
    } else {
      alert('Please select Caldendar, and then Publication');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: on focus event you need to call the api data & once response come open auto complete option

Comment: @Parth please elaborate if possible !!

Answer (score 0):

Write Code like below :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getLookup();
}
```

in getLookup() function Write down code of WEB API For Getting Data like Below:

```
public getLookup(){
    this.isLoading = true;

    this.article
      .postArticlesData({
        pubid: this.selectedPub.PubId,
        pubdate: this.selectedDate,
      })
      .subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
          this.isLoading = false;
          this.allArticles = data.result || [];

          this.articles = this.allArticles.filter((p) => {
            let title = p.Title.toLowerCase();
            return title.substring(0, kl) == k.toLowerCase();
          });
        },
        (e) => {
          this.isLoading = false;
        }
      );
}
```

Now Your lookup value is fill with value you just need to click on autocomplete show value.

Comment: there must be issue with `getLookup()` it says `Cannot find name 'getLookup'`

Comment: getLookup is function which need to put after ngOnInit()

Comment: I did put now what about autocomplete function ? `keyupArticle()` function cannot remove beacuse it is use in autocomplete, I have uploaded my code fully Please check.

Comment: yes you can keep it as it is. finally what happen at the first time when page load then it takes the value of dropdown and fill it so when user click on autocomplete then it shows the options & if you want to remove KeyupArticle() function then also it work fine but it not takes value of autocomplete when user type into autocomplete component. it depend on you what you want

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/4q0ZHUH) see got lot of errors man!

Comment: Dear In given link error show because you have put your function outside the component bracts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235058/discussion-between-parth-and-archana).